# Windows message eventListener doesn't work after signin again

Tags: javascript, html, window, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am making an application where I have to use **two iframes**,

- one for the *form* (`index.html`)
- the other for the *dropdown selection*.(`postmessage.js`)

**Scenario(1):-** When the user signs in for the first time, then the `check email()` function in `index.html` checks for the email. If email is empty, `send_msg()` send `msg=0` and if *not empty* `send_msg()` send `msg=1`.

**Scenario(2):-** when the user logs out and again *sign in*, then the `check email()` function in `index.html` doesn't check for the email.

**Condition:-** My user is not reloading the page while doing so.

**Conclusion**:- the check mail function should work again if the user signs in without reloading.

[image: iframes]

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <label>Email : </label><input type="email" name="email" /><br />
      <label>Phone : </label><input type="phone" name="phone" /><br />
      <label>Credit card v2: </label><input type="text" name="ccnum" /><br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
      document
        .getElementsByName("email")[0]
        .addEventListener("blur", function (event) {
          checkEmail();
        });
      document
        .getElementsByName("phone")[0]
        .addEventListener("blur", function (event) {
          //checkEmail();
        });
      document
        .getElementsByName("ccnum")[0]
        .addEventListener("focus", function (event) {
          send_msg("4");
        });
      document
        .getElementsByName("ccnum")[0]
        .addEventListener("blur", function (event) {
          send_msg("5");
        });

      function checkEmail() {
        let email = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;
        if (email.length == 0) {
          send_msg("0");
        }
      }

      function checkEmailLoad() {
        let email = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;
        if (email.length == 0) {
          send_msg("0");
        } else {
          send_msg("1");
        }
      }

      window.addEventListener(
        "message",
        (event) => {
          if (event.data == "1") {
            checkEmail();
          }
        },
        false
      );

      window.onload = function (e) {
        console.log("window.onload");
        checkEmailLoad();
      };

      function send_msg(msg) {
        window.top.frames[1].postMessage(msg, "https://smshub.ca:8443/crm/");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> post_message.js

```
window.allowSelection = false;
var slc = dijit.byId("result");

window.removeEventListener("message", function () {});

window.addEventListener(
  "message",
  (event) => {
    console.log("Received " + event.data);
    if (event.data == "1") {
      window.allowSelection = true;
    } else if (event.data == "0") {
      window.allowSelection = false;
      slc.attr("value", "");
    } else if (event.data == "4") {
      window.toggleRec(0);
    } else if (event.data == "5") {
      window.toggleRec(1);
    }
  },
  false
);

// function send_msg(msg) {
//   window.top.frames[1].postMessage(msg, "*");
// }

function checkSelection(dropdownValue) {
  if (
    (dropdownValue == "For Closers" ||
      dropdownValue == "Info Confirmed  No Points - ForC" ||
      dropdownValue == "No Info  No Points - ForCl") &&
    !window.allowSelection
  ) {
    slc.attr("value", "");
    Brekeke.dojo.dialog.alert("Email address is missing.");
  }
}

slc.on("change", function (evt) {
  checkSelection(evt);
});
```

Comment: The user signs in by completing the form and clicking `submit`? Where is the Javascript assigned to the `submit` button that logs the user in but doesn't refresh the page??

Comment: Where are these `iframes` you mention?

Comment: `postmessage.js` is the *first iframe* and `index.html` is the *second iframe*.

Comment: when the user enters an email, at that time the `check email ` function should work,i.e. it is not working. When I select "For Closers " it shows email address missing but I have entered the mail.

Comment: So if these two elements(postmessage.js & index.html) are `iframes` - or the contents of `iframes` - where is the hosting page?

Comment: I have edited it, so you can have a visual representation of the issue, now as I have entered the email, For Closers still gives an error email address mising.